# Block missed despite no problem on servers

Tags: stake-pool, block-production, leaderlog

My pool missed a block but looking at the server logs everything was fine at this moment.

Here are the Cardano logs :

```
{"thread":"1734","loc":null,"data" {"kind":"TraceStartLeadershipCheck","chainDensity":4.882958e-2,"slot":40969729,"delegMapSize":861059,"utxoSize":3467585,"credentials":"Cardano"},"sev":"Info","env":"1.29.0:4c594","msg":"","app":[],"host":"deploy-s","pid":"80","ns":["cardano.node.LeadershipCheck"],"at":"2021-09-25T02:13:40.00Z"}
{"thread":"1734","loc":null,"data":{"val": {"kind":"TraceNodeNotLeader","slot":40969729},"credentials":"Cardano"},"sev":"Info","env":"1.29.0:4c594","msg":"","app":[],"host":"deploy-s","pid":"80","ns":["cardano.node.Forge"],"at":"2021-09-25T02:13:40.00Z"}
{"thread":"1734","loc":null,"data":{"kind":"TraceStartLeadershipCheck","chainDensity":4.882958e-2,"slot":40969730,"delegMapSize":861059,"utxoSize":3467585,"credentials":"Cardano"},"sev":"Info","env":"1.29.0:4c594","msg":"","app":[],"host":"deploy-s","pid":"80","ns":["cardano.node.LeadershipCheck"],"at":"2021-09-25T02:13:41.00Z"}
{"thread":"1734","loc":null,"data":{"val":{"kind":"TraceNodeIsLeader","slot":40969730},"credentials":"Cardano"},"sev":"Info","env":"1.29.0:4c594","msg":"","app":[],"host":"deploy-s","pid":"80","ns":["cardano.node.Forge"],"at":"2021-09-25T02:13:41.00Z"}
{"thread":"217610","loc":null,"data":{"kind":"ChainSyncClientEvent.TraceDownloadedHeader","peer":{"remote":{"addr":"10.45.129.61","port":"6000"},"local":{"addr":"100.64.5.177","port":"43899"}},"slot":40969728,"block":"3e41596123fca52a1328fdf70c6986be9b57e9b3a5284d0232632aae4cf5affb","blockNo":6287888},"sev":"Info","env":"1.29.0:4c594","msg":"","app":[],"host":"deploy-s","pid":"80","ns":["cardano.node.ChainSyncClient"],"at":"2021-09-25T02:13:41.11Z"}
{"thread":"1736","loc":null,"data":{"peers":[{"length":"1","kind":"FetchDecision results","peer":{"remote":{"addr":"10.45.129.61","port":"6000"},"local":{"addr":"100.64.5.177","port":"43899"}}}],"kind":"PeersFetch"},"sev":"Info","env":"1.29.0:4c594","msg":"","app":[],"host":"deploy-s","pid":"80","ns":["cardano.node.BlockFetchDecision"],"at":"2021-09-25T02:13:41.14Z"}
{"thread":"1736","loc":null,"data":{"kind":"AddedFetchRequest","peer":{"remote":{"addr":"10.45.129.61","port":"6000"},"local":{"addr":"100.64.5.177","port":"43899"}}},"sev":"Info","env":"1.29.0:4c594","msg":"","app":[],"host":"deploy-s","pid":"80","ns":["cardano.node.BlockFetchClient"],"at":"2021-09-25T02:13:41.14Z"}
{"thread":"217608","loc":null,"data":{"kind":"AcknowledgedFetchRequest","peer":{"remote":{"addr":"10.45.129.61","port":"6000"},"local":{"addr":"100.64.5.177","port":"43899"}}},"sev":"Info","env":"1.29.0:4c594","msg":"","app":[],"host":"deploy-s","pid":"80","ns":["cardano.node.BlockFetchClient"],"at":"2021-09-25T02:13:41.16Z"}
{"thread":"217608","loc":null,"data":{"length":1,"kind":"SendFetchRequest","head":"3e41596123fca52a1328fdf70c6986be9b57e9b3a5284d0232632aae4cf5affb","peer":{"remote":{"addr":"10.45.129.61","port":"6000"},"local":{"addr":"100.64.5.177","port":"43899"}}},"sev":"Info","env":"1.29.0:4c594","msg":"","app":[],"host":"deploy-s","pid":"80","ns":["cardano.node.BlockFetchClient"],"at":"2021-09-25T02:13:41.16Z"}
{"thread":"217607","loc":null,"data":{"kind":"StartedFetchBatch","peer":{"remote":{"addr":"10.45.129.61","port":"6000"},"local":{"addr":"100.64.5.177","port":"43899"}}},"sev":"Info","env":"1.29.0:4c594","msg":"","app":[],"host":"deploy-s","pid":"80","ns":["cardano.node.BlockFetchClient"],"at":"2021-09-25T02:13:41.22Z"}
{"thread":"1734","loc":null,"data":{"val":{"kind":"TraceForgedBlock","blockPrev":"78de58439fc25a623ca44b8b7945385a23a727dc81a562f8aea54b3fa8dce4e5","slot":40969730,"block":"e16eb1d6ff408c4ada4f9f2fbdf554f7821ccd8d6b4a302c93aab8c3be0b22ff","blockNo":6287888},"credentials":"Cardano"},"sev":"Info","env":"1.29.0:4c594","msg":"","app":[],"host":"deploy-s","pid":"80","ns":["cardano.node.Forge"],"at":"2021-09-25T02:13:41.29Z"}
{"thread":"217607","loc":null,"data":{"kind":"CompletedBlockFetch","peer":{"remote":{"addr":"10.45.129.61","port":"6000"},"local":{"addr":"100.64.5.177","port":"43899"}},"block":"3e41596123fca52a1328fdf70c6986be9b57e9b3a5284d0232632aae4cf5affb"},"sev":"Info","env":"1.29.0:4c594","msg":"","app":[],"host":"deploy-s","pid":"80","ns":["cardano.node.BlockFetchClient"],"at":"2021-09-25T02:13:41.32Z"}
{"thread":"217607","loc":null,"data":{"kind":"CompletedFetchBatch","peer":{"remote":{"addr":"10.45.129.61","port":"6000"},"local":{"addr":"100.64.5.177","port":"43899"}}},"sev":"Info","env":"1.29.0:4c594","msg":"","app":[],"host":"deploy-s","pid":"80","ns":["cardano.node.BlockFetchClient"],"at":"2021-09-25T02:13:41.32Z"}
{"thread":"1724","loc":null,"data":{"newtip":"3e41596123fca52a1328fdf70c6986be9b57e9b3a5284d0232632aae4cf5affb@40969728","chainLengthDelta":1,"kind":"TraceAddBlockEvent.AddedToCurrentChain"},"sev":"Notice","env":"1.29.0:4c594","msg":"","app":[],"host":"deploy-s","pid":"80","ns":["cardano.node.ChainDB"],"at":"2021-09-25T02:13:41.49Z"}
{"thread":"217591","loc":null,"data":{"kind":"ChainSyncServerEvent.TraceChainSyncServerReadBlocked.AddBlock","slot":40969728,"block":"3e41596123fca52a1328fdf70c6986be9b57e9b3a5284d0232632aae4cf5affb","blockNo":6287888},"sev":"Info","env":"1.29.0:4c594","msg":"","app":[],"host":"deploy-s","pid":"80","ns":["cardano.node.ChainSyncHeaderServer"],"at":"2021-09-25T02:13:41.49Z"}
{"thread":"217591","loc":null,"data":{"point":{"kind":"BlockPoint","headerHash":"3e41596123fca52a1328fdf70c6986be9b57e9b3a5284d0232632aae4cf5affb","slot":40969728},"kind":"ChainSyncServerEvent.TraceChainSyncRollForward"},"sev":"Info","env":"1.29.0:4c594","msg":"","app":[],"host":"deploy-s","pid":"80","ns":["cardano.node.ChainSyncHeaderServer"],"at":"2021-09-25T02:13:41.49Z"}
{"thread":"1724","loc":null,"data":{"kind":"TraceAddBlockEvent.TrySwitchToAFork","block":{"kind":"Point","hash":"e16eb1d6ff408c4ada4f9f2fbdf554f7821ccd8d6b4a302c93aab8c3be0b22ff","slot":40969730}},"sev":"Info","env":"1.29.0:4c594","msg":"","app":[],"host":"deploy-s","pid":"80","ns":["cardano.node.ChainDB"],"at":"2021-09-25T02:13:41.49Z"}
{"thread":"1882","loc":null,"data":{"kind":"ChainSyncServerEvent.TraceChainSyncServerReadBlocked.AddBlock","slot":40969728,"block":"3e41596123fca52a1328fdf70c6986be9b57e9b3a5284d0232632aae4cf5affb","blockNo":6287888},"sev":"Info","env":"1.29.0:4c594","msg":"","app":[],"host":"deploy-s","pid":"80","ns":["cardano.node.ChainSyncHeaderServer"],"at":"2021-09-25T02:13:41.49Z"}
{"thread":"1882","loc":null,"data":{"point":{"kind":"BlockPoint","headerHash":"3e41596123fca52a1328fdf70c6986be9b57e9b3a5284d0232632aae4cf5affb","slot":40969728},"kind":"ChainSyncServerEvent.TraceChainSyncRollForward"},"sev":"Info","env":"1.29.0:4c594","msg":"","app":[],"host":"deploy-s","pid":"80","ns":["cardano.node.ChainSyncHeaderServer"],"at":"2021-09-25T02:13:41.49Z"}
{"thread":"1734","loc":null,"data":{"val":{"kind":"TraceDidntAdoptBlock","slot":40969730},"credentials":"Cardano"},"sev":"Error","env":"1.29.0:4c594","msg":"","app":[],"host":"deploy-s","pid":"80","ns":["cardano.node.Forge"],"at":"2021-09-25T02:13:41.51Z"}
{"thread":"1732","loc":null,"data":{"txs":[{"txid":"txid: TxId {_unTxId = SafeHash \"b1733a284ed3d44aef1db34bbafee20f0882a2478bc3b694c67fcd7dacb7258d\"}"},{"txid":"txid: TxId {_unTxId = SafeHash \"f8c92325873b728b22655f91b9c330d1f8e69c7632d444e291c3955d50bc4f20\"}"},{"txid":"txid: TxId {_unTxId = SafeHash \"5600ecfce06658369f4ad4fa21c1f841b40a8e799116734e7bae81b4fd5c81e3\"}"},{"txid":"txid: TxId {_unTxId = SafeHash \"08cf32b2b8cb9b54f6894b784997a84a98db44783d60322d618f6b38be798e69\"}"},{"txid":"txid: TxId {_unTxId = SafeHash \"fafb77fe479b34041e38881639fd92a84d4910867ac9f10b792058214d1708e7\"}"}],"mempoolSize":{"numTxs":1,"bytes":1495},"kind":"TraceMempoolRemoveTxs"},"sev":"Info","env":"1.29.0:4c594","msg":"","app":[],"host":"deploy-s","pid":"80","ns":["cardano.node.Mempool"],"at":"2021-09-25T02:13:41.79Z"}
{"thread":"1734","loc":null,"data":{"kind":"TraceStartLeadershipCheck","chainDensity":4.885721e-2,"slot":40969731,"delegMapSize":861059,"utxoSize":3467587,"credentials":"Cardano"},"sev":"Info","env":"1.29.0:4c594","msg":"","app":[],"host":"deploy-s","pid":"80","ns":["cardano.node.LeadershipCheck"],"at":"2021-09-25T02:13:42.00Z"}
```

I see that there is a "TraceAddBlockEvent.TrySwitchToAFork" event during my leader slot, is it the cause of my problem ? Can I do something to avoid that in the future ?

Comment: How do you see this skipping / missed? I see `40969729, 40969730, 40969731` is that the block serial? Seems legit. Maybe I don't know what slot is.

Comment: @Tomachi I have this in the logs {"kind":"TraceDidntAdoptBlock","slot":40969730}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if you forge a block in a slot but the node switches to a different fork before your block is propagated, your node with increment the metric tracking that it forged but didn't adopt it.

Comment: OK it sounds a bit like an "Uncle" block in Ethereum yes? AFAIK in Ethereum these get acknowledged in the next block but with lesser rewards, I guess it would make the chain harder to forge so makes sense. I wonder if Cardano uses these blocks? Or is the counter just for internal use to diagnose slow propagation issues maybe.